# Interpret javascript in vim using SingleCompile

Tags: javascript, vim, plugins

I have installed SingleCompile plugin in vim. I have tested compiling "C" program and it was successful.

When tried for javascript, it says "No compiler is available for this language". Does anybody have idea about how to go with it?

Thanks,
Anji

Comment: @bdares so is it not possible to interpret js in vim? [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) it shows javascript is supported.

Comment: Do you have any of the listed interpreters installed on your machine?

Comment: @romainl It works fine now. Thanks for your comment. Have installed node and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript isn't a compiled language, so is perfectly clear that is "no compiler available"

Edit: Just saw that SingleCompile have JS interpreter support also.
So my idea is that you haven't the right interpreter installed

Comment: Yeah I am aware of it. But there are only two commands available `:SingleCompile` and `:SingleCompileRun` and there is no `:SingleInterpret`. I have also tried doing `:SCChooseInterpret` which also resulted the same message

Comment: SingleCompile home pages shows that, it has some default  built-in supported interpreters/compilers. Check [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115).

Comment: @Anji i'd alredy read it... But i suppose that they're anchor to interpreter and compiler that you have on your own machine.

Comment: Anyhelp about installing the required packages and also linking them?

Comment: @Anji Read SingleCompile.vim file (should exists one) or try to install one of the listed interpreter to make a test